# Automatically clock in when I switch task mode to "in progress"

Tags: org-mode, org-clock, todo

Title is pretty self-explanatory. I apologize for not being able to figure this out myself, I'm new to emacs.
When I switch a task from 'todo' to 'in-progress', I would like emacs to automatically clock me in, then when I switch it out of 'in progress' I would like to clock out.

I understand this will need to use variables org-clock-out, org-clock-in, etc., but none of the solutions I have found online seem to work… e.g., [this](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2009-04/msg00315.html) gives me a "and: Symbol’s value as variable is void: state" error.

Thanks for your help; cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. Much simpler than the linked solution.

```lisp
    (add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook
              'org-clock-todo-change)
    
    (defun org-clock-todo-change ()
      (if (string= org-state "IN-PROGRESS")
          (org-clock-in)
        (org-clock-out)))
```

Comment: There might be some funny behavior with this sol. and repeater. See [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/71192/repeater-broken-after-edits-to-org-after-todo-state-change-hook) post for updates.