# Repeater broken after edits to org-after-todo-state-change-hook

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, todo

Title is pretty self explanatory. I have implemented the below solution to 'clock in' when I change my org-todo state to IN-PROGRESS and 'clock out' when I leave that state.

```
(add-hook 'org-after-todo-state-change-hook
          'org-clock-todo-change)

(defun org-clock-todo-change ()
  (if (string= org-state "IN-PROGRESS")
      (org-clock-in)
      (org-clock-out)))
```

The problem is that when I make this change, my repeating tasks stop working correctly.
e.g., if I have a repeating task

```
*** TODO Take vitamins
    SCHEDULED: <2022-03-31 Thu .+1d>
```

And mark it 'DONE', I would expect to see the behavior described [here](https://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html), so something like

```
*** TODO Take vitamins
    SCHEDULED: <2022-04-01 Fri .+1d>
```

But instead I see

```
*** DONE Take vitamins
    CLOSED: [2022-03-30 Wed 18:50] SCHEDULED: <2022-03-31 Thu .+1d>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you sure that the reason is the change in the hook? What happens if you set the hook to `nil`?

Comment: @NickD  The first block of code is what's producing the bug. When I comment it out, there's normal behavior as specified in documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `org-clock-out` without any special precautions and there is no clock running, it will throw an error and not continue on. The doc string says:

> (org-clock-out &optional SWITCH-TO-STATE FAIL-QUIETLY AT-TIME)
>
> Stop the currently running clock.
> Throw an error if there is no running clock and FAIL-QUIETLY is nil.

So try calling it like this:

```el
(defun org-clock-todo-change ()
  (if (string= org-state "IN-PROGRESS")
      (org-clock-in)
    (org-clock-out nil t)))
```

But do you really want to stop the clock if it's *not* running in the curren task? It seems to me that what you'd really want to do is `(org-clock-out-if-current)`. So I would try

```
(defun org-clock-todo-change ()
  (if (string= org-state "IN-PROGRESS")
      (org-clock-in)
    (org-clock-out-if-current)))
```

instead. That way if you switch a task to `IN-PROGRESS` and start a clock on it (thereby stopping the clock on a different task that is `IN-PROGRESS`) and then you go to that other task and switch it to `DONE`, the clock on the original task will still be running. It's only when you switch *that* task to `DONE` that the clock will be stopped.

I should caution you that I don't know much about clocking, so take this with the appropriate grain of salt.

Comment: 'org-clock-out-if-current' was what I was looking for. Nice spot on error. Cheers.